# Removing planeDetection planes prevents placing additional planes

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am generating planes using ARKit and if I manually remove the plane I am unable to detect planes it the same position.

To detect planes I set the scene config

```
 let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.worldAlignment = .gravity
        config.providesAudioData = false
        config.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
       ...
        else if ARMode == .floor {
            self.ARMode = .floor
            scannerBox.isHidden=true
            focusNode?.isHidden=false
            plusButton.isHidden=true
            config.planeDetection = .horizontal            self.planeTexture="test.scnassets/Textures/Surface_Texture.png"
        }
        ...

        sceneView.session.run(config)
```

Add plane to the scene in renderer function

```
       let planeNode = self.createARPlaneNode(planeAnchor: planeAnchor,
                                                   color: UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5))

            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

If a certain button is pushed the plane and other objects should be removed

```
scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        print(node.name)
        if (node.name == "sphere" ) {
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
         if ( node.name == "surfacePlane") {

                 node.removeFromParentNode()
           }

        if(node.name != nil){
            if (node.name?.contains("ProductModel_"))!  {
                node.removeFromParentNode()

            }
        }    
    }
```

When the above code fires the planes, spheres, and products disappear as expected.
If I try to scan the surface elsewhere in the room it works as expected but if I try to scan where the plane was and generate a new one it will not work.  It will not generate a new plane and if nearby planes expand to cover the same area they disappear.

I believe the problem is likely the scene geometry of the removed planes is somehow still present and preventing new planes in the same space.
As a temporary work around I and stopping and starting the AR sessions and that removes the planes.

```
     let config = sceneView.session.configuration as!
        ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
        config.planeDetection = .horizontal
        sceneView.session.run(config,
                              options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

I am trying to determine why this is the case and the planes aren't treated the same as objects I explicitly placed in the scene.

Comment: Why not just remove the children of the plane rather than the plane itself? Once `didAddAnchor` is called for an `ARPlaneAnchor` it won't be called again without resetting the session as you've said.

Comment: I want the existing planes removed so that when I move to the new state of the app the previous environment objects and panes don't interfere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to remove the ARPlaneAnchor your plane node was attached to so that ARKit will create a new ARPlaneAnchor and kick off the renderer function that is creating your plane node.

Something like

```
      if ( node.name == "surfacePlane") {
          if let planeAnchor = sceneView.anchor(for: node) as? ARPlaneAnchor {
              sceneView.session.remove(anchor: planeAnchor)
          }
          node.removeFromParentNode()
      }
```